# Screwed everything up after installing wine

Tags: wine, package-management

Note: I'm an ubuntu noob

When I try to install anything, say filezilla... I get this:

I type sudo apt-get install filezilla

Type in my password

I get:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies.
filezilla : Depends: libtinyxml2.6.2 but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: libwxbase2.8-0 (>= 2.8.12.1) but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: libwxgtk2.8-0 (>= 2.8.12.1) but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: filezilla-common (= 3.5.3-1ubuntu2) but it is not going to      be     installed
     wine1.6 : Depends: wine1.6-amd64 (= 1.6~rc2-0ubuntu1~ppa4) but 1.6~rc2-0ubuntu1~ppa1 is to be installed
           Depends: wine1.6-i386 (= 1.6~rc2-0ubuntu1~ppa4)
 wine1.6-amd64 : Depends: wine1.6:any (= 1.6~rc2-0ubuntu1~ppa1)
 wine1.6-i386:i386 : Depends: wine1.6:any:i386 (= 1.6~rc2-0ubuntu1~ppa1)
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
caitlan@caitlan-iMac:~$
```

So I try sudo apt-get -f install:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libdrm-nouveau2 libxrandr-ltsq2 libllvm3.1
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following extra packages will be installed:
  wine1.6 wine1.6-amd64 wine1.6-i386:i386
Suggested packages:
  dosbox:any
The following packages will be upgraded:
  wine1.6 wine1.6-amd64 wine1.6-i386:i386
3 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 272 not upgraded.
4 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 50.7 MB of archives.
After this operation, 1,162 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? ^Ccaitlan@caitlan-iMac:~$
```

I type in y

```
Get:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu/ precise/main wine1.6-amd64 amd64 1.6~rc4-0ubuntu1 [24.9 MB]
Get:2 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu/ precise/main wine1.6 amd64 1.6~rc4-0ubuntu1 [1,177 kB]
Get:3 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu/ precise/main wine1.6-i386 i386 1.6~rc4-0ubuntu1 [24.6 MB]
Fetched 50.7 MB in 48s (1,044 kB/s)                                            
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of wine1.6-amd64:
 wine1.6-amd64 depends on wine1.6:any (= 1.6~rc2-0ubuntu1~ppa1); however:
  Version of wine1.6 on system is 1.6~rc2-0ubuntu1~ppa4.
dpkg: error processing wine1.6-amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of wine1.6:
 wine1.6 depends on wine1.6-amd64 (= 1.6~rc2-0ubuntu1~ppa4); however:
  Version of wine1.6-amd64 on system is 1.6~rc2-0ubuntu1~ppa1.
 wine1.6 depends on wine1.6-i386 (= 1.6~rc2-0ubuntu1~ppa4); however:
  Package wine1.6-i386 is not installed.
  Version of wine1.6-i386:i386 on system is 1.6~rc2-0ubuntu1~ppa1.
dpkg: error processing wine1.6 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of wine1.6-i386:i386:
 wine1.6-i386:i386 depends on wine1.6:any (= 1.6~rc2-0ubuntu1~ppa1); however:
  Version of wine1.6 on system is 1.6~rc2-0ubuntu1~ppa4.
dpkg: error processing wine1.6-i386:i386 (--configNo apport report written because the error message indicates it's a follow-up error from a previous failure.
                                                                              No apport report written because the error message indicates it's a follow-up error from a previous failure.
                          No apport report written because the error message indicates it's a follow-up error from a previous failure.
                                                      ure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of wine:
 wine depends on wine1.6; however:
  Package wine1.6 is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing wine (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 wine1.6-amd64
 wine1.6
 wine1.6-i386:i386
 wine
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
caitlan@caitlan-iMac:~$
```

If I go on software centre, I get: 
items cannot be installed or removed until the package catalogue is repaired

HELP?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you just need to refresh the repositories. Try:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Then see if that makes a difference.

Comment: W: GPG error: http://ppa.launchpad.net precise Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 2EA8F35793D8809A

Comment: Hmmm...looks like a broken installation. Did you upgrade to 13.04 with an already installed system, or did you install Ubuntu fresh off the CD? If you upgraded, the upgrade probably failed at some point, or was interrupted.

Answer (score 0):

I will advise this [Q/A](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies), 
I think your distribution upgrade didn't finish completely.
you should follow the solutions on this link.
Looking for the results soon...